# Is it possible to start job from another job?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute job from another job by two different ways, but in the first case I'm getting an error, in second - don't retrieve output from wrapped job.

Here is my code:

Variant 1:

```
$joba = {
    param(
        $st
    )
    $st | Write-Output
    return $st
}


$jobb = {
    param(
        $strng,
        $ja
    )

    "Trying to execute joba with $strng parameter..." | Write-Output
    Start-Job -Name JA $ja -ArgumentList $strng
    Receive-Job -Name $ja
}

$quack = "woof"
$result = Start-Job -Name JB $jobb -ArgumentList $quack
Receive-Job JB
```

Variant 2:

```
$jobb = {
    param(
        $strng
    )

    $joba = {
        param(
            $st
        )
        $st | Write-Output
        return $st
    }

    "Trying to execute joba with $strng parameter..." | Write-Output
    $ja = Start-Job -Name JA $joba -ArgumentList $strng
    Receive-Job -Job $ja
}

$quack = "woof"
$result = Start-Job -Name JB $jobb -ArgumentList $quack
Receive-Job JB
```

**UPD 1** (error message for case 1):

```
Cannot bind the argument to the "ScriptBlock" parameter because it is NULL.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Cannot bind the argument to the "Job" parameter because it is NULL.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Receive-Job], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReceiveJobCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: Please don't write "getting an error" without posting the actual error text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think you have to check this link it's speak about how to waiting job :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-6
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-6

And i think this example can help you :

```
   $jobb = {
    param($strng,$ja)

    # $strng |Write-Output
    # $ja | Write-Output
    $joba = {
        param($st)
        Write-Host $st
        return $st
    }


    Write-Host "Trying to execute joba with $strng parameter..." 
    $myRunJobA = Start-Job -Name:"JA"  -ArgumentList:@($strng) -ScriptBlock:$joba
    # $myRunJobA
    $resultJobA = Receive-Job -Job:$myRunJobA -Wait
    # Write-Host $myRunJobA
}

$quack = "woof"
$myRunJobB = Start-Job -Name:"JB" -ArgumentList:@($quack) -ScriptBlock:$jobb
$resultJobB = Receive-Job -Job:$myRunJobB -Wait
```