# acessing and using json array simultaneously in powershell for parallel execution

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have a json in which array is defined and has multiple elements. Each of these elements are to be passed to a function for certain action. This is done now using foreach loop and is a sequential process. I want to extract all elements of json array at a time and call function (it's multiple thread ) to simultaneously work on data.

Code is there but for now it is a sequential process which takes time. This data can be used simultaneously and could help to bring down time for function to act on entire set of data

```
{
  "server": [
    {
      "name": "P1",
      "description": "Descr",
      "connection": [
        {
          "name": "TestProfile",
          "general": {
            "sname": "uweyruw"
            .........
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TestProfile1",
          "general": {
            "sname": "SAN_A"
            ..........
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "P2",
      "description": "Descr",
      "connection": [
        {
          "name": "TestProfile",
          "general": {
            "sname": "uweyruw"
            .........
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TestProfile1",
          "general": {
            "sname": "SAN_A"
            ..........
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



$CR_JSON_Path = "C:\json\CR.json"

$CR_JSON = Get-Content -Path $CR_JSON_Path | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($server in $CR_JSON.serverProfile) {

    $result = Create_Server_Profile -ServerProfile $server 
    -Existing_server $Existing_server

    if($result.status -eq "fail") {
        $Script:status = $false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Within your JSON, I assume the `..........` contains a `ServerProfile` somewhere? If so then you would need to call `$CR_JSON.server.serverProfile`. If you are trying to get `TestProfile` or `TestProfile1` then you need to call `$CR_JSON.server.Connection.name`

Comment: You can create a runspacepool and after that use a foreach loop to create runspaces for each machine you want to target.

Comment: Hi, you can take look at Start-Job, Wait-Job and other parallelism cdmlets :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398048/is-it-possible-to-start-job-from-another-job/54400018#54400018

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am a newbie on PowerShell will try with methods that have been suggested